# Asynchronous loop with callback not working in IE or Firefox

Tags: javascript

Quick rundown on what I'm trying to do. I have a `for` loop creating an array using the value of `i`, where `i` goes from 0 to a rather high number (90000+). While in the for loop, I want to have a counter that updates some text on the screen (basically a percentage of how far along it is). I also need to use the array, when the loop is finished. So far the only thing I've gotten working is the following (a basic example):

```
(function(callback) {
    var counterText = document.getElementById('text');
    for (var i=0; i<100001; i++) {
        (function(index) {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                counterText.innerHTML = index;
                if (index+1 === i) callback();
            }, 0);
        })(i);
    }
})(function(data) {
    alert("DONE");
});
```

This works perfectly in Chrome. But in FF and IE(11), the text doesn't update until after the loop is complete and then you see the alert and text at the same time.

I've tried a number of different things. Almost everything I've come across regarding a DOM counter and loops uses some form of an `if` statement instead of a `for` loop. The problem with using an `if` is that it seems to be magnitudes slower than a `for`, to the point of being unusable with the size of looping I need.

I'm not sure why the above function doesn't work in FF/IE.

jsfiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/uxs84g1y/1/

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to see the counter increment, instead of seing only the last value. Try using a recursive function instead of the foor loop. The for loop launches the calls to `setTimeout` almost simultaneously, so it's normal that you see only the result from the last call.

Comment: I assume you mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kan777ab/) mef? The problem with using `if` is that it takes so long. The for loop can go from 0 to 100000 in a couple seconds. An if would take much, much, long and just be unrealistic to use. Regarding your last sentence, in Chrome I don't just see the result from the last call (again, remember I'm going from 0 to large numbers so it's not instantaneous). It's only in FF and IE where it waits until the loop is finished before showing anything.

Comment: Using `counter`, `index` *and* `i` in that code makes it a little hard to follow.

Comment: A timeout of `0` is too small. Some browsers will not give control to the renderer and continue executing JS when they encounter such a timeout. Try a bigger value. Also, you might want to use a semi-recursive function instead of a loop that creates thousands of timeouts at once.

Comment: @Bergi, I removed `counter` from my original code. Hopefully easier to follow. I've tried different timeout values, from 0 to over a second. But that just delays when it starts the actual "counting". I've also tried various recursive methods but everything I've done is just way too slow (example of recursive method I've done is in one of my above comments).

Comment: If you want to display the progress of a processing, I'd recommend you to first develop the process you want to do (you mentioned some array in your question, which we do not see in the example code). Then you'll be in measure to properly implement what you're looking to do (and probably get rid of the `setTimeout`). updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kan777ab/1/

Comment: I left out the array in my above example, but I do have that whole process worked out. Basically, I'm generating simplex/perlin noise and it uses the value of i in my for loop to do so (so for each value of i it generates height data. That was all just extra stuff that wasn't really applicable here. I'm curious (and confused) why my above example works in Chrome and not in FF/IE. I've tried recursive examples (like your example) but it takes forever to go from 0 to 90000+. The iterative method/for loop does that in a couple seconds. Recursion takes just way to long to be usable.

Comment: Firefox and IE must simply be skipping the DOM "redraw" at each timeOut, because the next timeOut is already firing, asking for a redraw of the same DOM node. setTimeout simply doesn't have its place in your code. Try to trigger less DOM updates, like in this version: http://jsfiddle.net/kan777ab/3/